# Mixing procedures and events

Tags: javascript, events, procedure

I have a function that loads an image and checks to see if it loads successfully. (To see if the browser supports WebP)

The problem is, I have to use onload() and onerror() for this, and that means I can't simply return a value.

**How can I can delay returning until the event fires?**

Here's my code:

```
function start_check_webp(){
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = '<img id = "test_image" src="test_image.webp">';
  webp_test = div.firstChild;
  div.firstChild.onerror = function(){support_webp = false}
  div.firstChild.onload = function(){support_webp = true}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You'll need to restructure your code to handle asynchronous events. Instead of having your event handlers set a variable, you could have them call a function which actually does something if WebP is supported or otherwise.

Comment: Alright... that was my other option, but I preferred getting a yes\no value. Just to check, there isn't any way to find out if the image loading failed without using events, is there?

Comment: @snostorm: Unfortunately no. The browser needs to first load the image from the server, which necessarily makes it asynchronous. (There are no blocking calls in JavaScript.)

Answer (score 0):

Structure your code so that it runs once the image is loaded. You can speed the process up by using a data URI instead of an external image eg

```
function testWepP() {
  var webP = new Image();     
  webP.src = 'data:image/webp;base64,UklGRjoAAABXRUJQVlA4IC4AAACyAgCdASoCAAIAL' + 
    'mk0mk0iIiIiIgBoSygABc6WWgAA/veff/0PP8bA//LwYAAA';
  webP.onload = webP.onerror = function () {
     callback(webP.height === 2);     
  }; 
};

testWebP(function(supported) {
  console.log((supported) ? "webP supported!" : "webP not supported."); 
});
```